# PHP - Redirected You Too Many Times Error On Server Not Localhost

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

I have a LAMP site running on an online server.
I tested the site on Localhost and it works fine.
I put the site on the server and got this error:

```
[SITE] redirected you too many times.
ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS
```

I tried clearing my Cookies but that didn't help.

I have my sites set up like this:

home.php:

```
if (!$user->is_logged_in) {
  die(header("Location: login.php"));
}
```

login.php:

```
if ($user->is_logged_in) {
  die(header("Location: home.php"));
}
```

is_logged_in is in the user class file set up as a variable for a _SESSION boolean.

The weird part is that I get the error message for a couple seconds before it redirects me to either the page I want or login.php. Even if I get redirected to login.php, when I refresh is_logged_in is still true so it redirects me to home.php.

I don't have a .htaccess file (that I know of).

Is this a problem with the server or my code? Any suggestions on what I can do to fix it? I think the pages aren't getting the user class variable is_logged_in in time but I'm not sure.

Comment: Can you reproduce this locally/not on your online server but with the same code? Just to see if the problem is not related to the server.

Comment: Yes. locally (localhost) the site works as expected. Online is where the error occurs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with the server I was using. Not sure what the main cause was, but when I changed to a different provider the site worked as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of putting `$user->is_logged_in` directly in the `if` statement, try using `isset($user->is_logged_in)`

```
if (!isset($user->is_logged_in)) {
 die(header("Location: login.php"));
}
```

And

```
if (isset($user->is_logged_in)) {
 die(header("Location: home.php"));
}
```

Comment: I still get the same error message (Too many redirects). I had is_logged_in initialized to false. I tried it with this and having it not be initialized. With isset() and is_logged_in initialized to false i was always redirected to the home page with no user content for login.php. And with isset() and is_logged_in not initialized i got the same error as before.